# How to extract day and month from a Date data in sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a column in my database `bornDate` which has this format `dd/MM/yyyy`. I want to extract the day and month to compare with the current day and month and in this way to select users who are born today

Comment: You already asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65464335/how-to-query-a-sqlite-database-to-obtain-users-who-are-born-today You should edit the original question to add additional info instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string functions:

```
select *
from mytable
where substr(bornadte, 1, 5) = strftime('%d/%m', 'now')
```

Note that you should not be storing dates in this format. SQLite understands dates [in format `YYYY-MM-DD`](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).  I would strongly recommend fixing your data model:

```
update mytable
set borndate = substr(borndate, -4) 
    || '-' ||  substr(borndate, 4, 2) 
    || '-' ||  substr(borndate, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Great answer +1 and I didn't think the date format was even salvagable.